# How to implement a datepicker in angular2 app?

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I have defined my html file as :

```
<span  id="datepicker" (click)="ShowDate()">
   <i class="fa fa-calendar " aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 20px;" ></i>
</span>
```

My requirement is that when I click on the span tag, a date picker should pop up.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Input type date should work.

```
<input type="date" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" [(ngModel)]="date">
```